# Showing that $I:k[x_1,\dots,x_n] = I$ for ideal $I \subseteq k[x_1,\dots,x_n]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ideals

I am trying to prove that $I:k[x_1,\dots,x_n] = I$ for ideal $I \subseteq k[x_1,\dots,x_n]$. Inclusion $I \subseteq I:k[x_1,\dots,x_n]$ is trivial as $I$ is an ideal. But I am not sure how to approach the second inclusion, $I:k[x_1,\dots,x_n] \subseteq I$. What the theorem is trying to say is that the elements of $I$ are exactly those elements which stay in $I$ under multiplication by any other element in the ambient polynomial ring. While this is part of the definition of an ideal, that $\forall f \in I.\forall g \in k[x_1,\dots,x_n].fg \in I$, I still don't think that $\forall f \in I:k[x_1,\dots,x_n].\forall g \in J.fg \in I$ implies that $I:k[x_1,\dots,x_n] \subseteq I$.

All hints are appreciated!

Edit: The quotient of ideals $I, J \subset k[x_1,\dots,x_n]$ is defined as $I:J = \{f \in k[x_1,\dots,x_n]\mid \forall g \in J.fg \in I\}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can replace $k[x_1,\ldots,x_n]$ with any commutative unital ring $R$. We want to show that $I:R\subseteq I$, i.e. for each $f\in R$ such that $fg\in I$ for all $g\in R$, we have $f\in I$. Take $g=1$.